Intel AMT: KVM only with external display connected?
I have set up Intel ME (v11.8.92) and use MeshCommander for access.
The remote deskop (KVM) works well, as long as I have an external monitor connected in the VGA port. But if I disconnect the external monitor (also with a power cycle), the KVM screen remains black. Sometimes I get a single blinking dash at the very beginning (where there should be the BIOS).
Is this normal? And is there a setting to enable KVM regardless of whether external display is connected?

As far as I know, this is normal behavior with AMT. It doesn't work the same way as iLO/iDRAC on servers – it is meant for remote management of workstations (desktops), not of headless systems, and the iGPU doesn't pretend to have an always-active output.
If there's no display connected, you have to connect one of those "dummy HDMI" or "EDID emulator" plugs that pretend to be a real display, so that the iGPU would generate output for AMT to capture.

wow, bummer. It seems to work when VGA cable is connected with monitor turned off. But I measure about 2W more power consumption. This 24x7 is not negligible.

Does the 2W come from your monitor in standby, or does it come from your GPU which is generating the output signal? If it's the former, replace it with a dummy plug (those exist also for VGA).

(Aside from that, 2 W continuous is 1.4 kWh per month, which is about €0.40/month in my local prices. I'd still call that negligible.)

Unfortunately it’s the latter because it works (and draws power) when monitor is unpowered. 2W is absolutely not negligible if you have hundreds of devices which all call themselves negligible

Remote Desktop (KVM) in Intel AMT requires a monitor to be constantly connected to the graphics card output, otherwise the graphics turns off and you only see black screen in the KVM. Connect the monitor emulator to the graphics output on your motherboard (D-Sub, HDMI, or DisplayPort) and the KVM will start working. You can buy a Dummy VGA/HDMI/DP Plug for pennies or make one yourself (https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=dummy+vga+plug).
BUT beware: if PC with Intel AMT you want to connect to via KVM has Linux OS installed, the simple Dummy VGA Plug with resistors is not sufficient.  In such a case you need monitor emulator with EDID data on chip, otherwise it will still be black after first few seconds from booting. You can also do it yourself for pennies, but you have to solder to VGA/HDMI/DP plug additionally a programmed eeprom memory (e.g. 24C02) with the EDID dump from some monitor. Cheap CH341A programmer for this task is quite sufficient.
